# ES6 module that exports dynamic content?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, dependency-injection, ecmascript-6, promise

This is a general question about how to deal with shifting data dependencies in an API.

I depend upon two data objects in my application:

```
1. mycompanyProducts
2. mycompanySettings
```

The products object looks like:

```
{
  "MYTHING01": {
    "sku": "MYTHING01",
    "name": "15-Pack",
    "price": 30,
    "shopifyData": {
      "id": "7987037995068",
      "product_id": "664292996940",
      "price": "30.00",
      "taxable": true,
      "inventory_quantity": 10,
      "weight": 2,
      "weight_unit": "kg",
      "lastFetched": {
        "$date": "2018-05-09T14:16:57.209Z"
      }
    }
  },
  "MYTHING02": {
    "sku": "MYTHING02",
    "name": "5-Pack",
    "price": 15,
    "shopifyData": {
      "id": "7836960168028",
      "product_id": "645959671756",
      "price": "15.00",
      "taxable": true,
      "inventory_quantity": 10,
      "weight": 2,
      "weight_unit": "kg",
      "lastFetched": {
        "$date": "2018-05-09T14:16:57.228Z"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the settings object simply contains application settings, like maximum image upload size in MB, etc.

Both of these objects are coming from MongoDb collections.

Here's the idea: I want to be able to update my collections, and have my API update its dependencies without having to rebuild. It would be very cumbersome to have to trigger API rebuilds based on Shopify webhooks (where some of the changes are coming from), etc.

Each product has a `shopifyData.lastFetched` timestamp, and when accessing the data, if the timestamp is more than some period (10 minutes) in the past, I want to refresh the data before continuing:

```
// Loop through each Shopify product and update the product in the db
await Promise.all(res.data.products.map(async (shopifyProduct) => {
  const variant = shopifyProduct.variants.find(v => mySKUs.includes(v.sku))
  product.shopifyData = {
    ...variant,
    lastFetched: new Date(),
  }
  await product.save()
}))
```

The question is: how can I structure my API to use updating dependencies? Obviously ES6 modules export statically, and won't change until the application is rebuilt.

I can of course export a *function* that returns the dependencies, and call this function when I need it for fresh deps, but the problem is that my function is necessarily `async`, so it's hard to call:

```
import React from 'react'
const deps = generateDeps() // can't use await in this scope...
```

Moreover, putting `const deps = generateDeps()` in the top of my files doesn't really solve the issue anyways, as this would be evaluated once, and only once.

How do people solve this problem?

Comment: It's not really clear why updates on Shopify products or collections should update your project dependencies. Like...updating a product means you'll need to load a *new*, different npm module into your project?

Comment: The reason I ask is because I intuitively feel like the reason you're having this problem is that you've structured something wrong in the first place. If you just need to have updating product information... that doesn't require anything as complicated as what you're asking for.

Comment: It seems you've conflated the concept of a data model the actual data and the access to the the data all into a single concept that you call _dependencies_. Only one of these things actually change in your scenario, and as TKoL points out, you don't need all this complication to update the data.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Clearly updating the data is the easy part. Imagine I changed `MYTHING02`'s weight. If other parts of my API _depend_ upon this weight - imagine an endpoint's validation checks against weight - how will this change happen? There's no need to be condescending.

Comment: Apologies - didn't mean to come off that way - it seems your dilemma is synchronization then. Solutions start with pub/sub at the simplest through reactive javascript (RxJS) style observables as most complex. Either subscribe to the data that changes and propagate those changes through custom events or observe the data and react to the change.

Answer (score 0):

You can import the function and call it async in your code :

```
import {generateDeps} from './depsGenerator'
//...
generateDeps().then(() => {
    //...
})
```

That way the timeout would be checked at every call

Answer (score 0):

Export a function and call it whenever you actually need to access the data, instead of at the top of a module.